# Problems to visualize huge network in R

Tags: r, networking

I have created a network of interactions between microRNAs and mRNAs following [this tutorial](https://www.jessesadler.com/post/network-analysis-with-r/). My problem is that my network, unlike the one in the tutorial is very big. How can I plot this with R?

```
> head(seed_edges)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   from    to weight
  <int> <int>  <int>
1    76   765      1
2    76  9624      1
3    76 11962      1
4    76 10583      1
5    76  5243      1
6    76  5326      1

> head(seed_nodes)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id label                                
  <int> <chr>                                
1     1 miR-124_3p      
2     2 miR-7_3p         
3     3 Mir-10_3p
4     4 39523_5p              
5     5 10399_3p              
6     6 39777_5p   

> seed_routes_network <- network(seed_edges, vertex.attr = seed_nodes, matrix.type = "edgelist", ignore.eval = FALSE)
> class(seed_routes_network)
[1] "network"

> seed_routes_network
 Network attributes:
  vertices = 45584 
  directed = TRUE 
  hyper = FALSE 
  loops = FALSE 
  multiple = FALSE 
  bipartite = FALSE 
  total edges= 2805445 
    missing edges= 0 
    non-missing edges= 2805445 

 Vertex attribute names: 
    id label vertex.names 

 Edge attribute names not shown 

>plot(seed_routes_network)
#can't plot, just leaves me waiting
```

Comment: won't a network graph with millions of edges just look like a blob?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it does feel dumb now my question. 
I was hoping I could zoom in